# Html not decoded in span is it Knockout.js or Jquery mobile doing things?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, html-encode

I am trying to display warning message that has special character `'` (`&#39;`) in span as text on a page that is using Jquery Mobile UI and knockout.js. Text is returned by javascript function and is encoded on .NET side. Problem is it gets interpreted as literal while same exact html in [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vdu9d/) is interpreted like `'`.

**Is it Knockout.js or JQuery Mobile again or am I missing something here?**

I have printed out function that returns the value in Chrome Dev tools in screenshot below, and you can see html too. 
[image]

Comment: I think the problem is that you are binding text and not html. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Vdu9d/1/. I don't know knockout.js but I saw there is a way to bind html.

Comment: @Spokey - post that as an answer

Comment: @Spokey I knockout-ified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/Vdu9d/3/) if you want to use it

Comment: @Spokey It's knockout, please post it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the string you want to append is an HTML entity and it won't be rendered if you [append it as text](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Vdu9d/1)

Thanks to @Origineil for providing the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/Vdu9d/3/) with knockout that proves the same thing.

```html
<span data-bind="text: data"></span><br/> <!-- &#39; -->
<span data-bind="html: data"></span>      <!-- ' -->
```

And script

```
var vm = {
    data: ko.observable('3 Optional Activities aren&#39;t Done')
};
ko.applyBindings(vm)
```